# MVC Core IActionResult meaning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What is an `IActionResult`? I tried looking at MSDN and other sites, but need general, common easy to understand answer.

[MSDN IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

**Example:**

```
public IActionResult About() {
    ViewData["Message"] = "About Page";
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general terms `IActionResult` type is a base abstraction of an action result. It is used as the base of other derived action results that represent specific response types, of which there are many.

Reference [Asp.Net Core Action Results Explained](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/)

> ## IActionResult and ActionResult
>
> IActionResult and ActionResult work as a container for other action results, in that IActionResult is an interface and ActionResult is an abstract class that other action results inherit from. So they can’t be newed up and returned like other action results. IActionResult and ActionResult have not much of a different from usability perspective, but since IActionResult is the intended contract for action results, it’s better to use it as opposed to ActionResult. IActionResult/ActionResult should be used to give us more flexibility, like when we need to return different type of response based on user interaction.

To quote official documentation Found here [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types#iactionresult-type)

> The IActionResult return type is appropriate when multiple ActionResult return types are possible in an action. The ActionResult types represent various HTTP status codes. Some common return types falling into this category are BadRequestResult (400), NotFoundResult (404), and OkObjectResult (200).

Answer (score 10):

`IActionResult` specifies how the server should respond to the request, such as  writing data to the response or returning an error status code.

For example, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult` serializes the object passed from the constructor and writes the serialized JSON data to the response and sets the MIME type to `application/JSON`. It can be understood as "*This request results as a JSON string*".