# Difference between defining web api methods - newbie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What is the difference between declaring WEB API methods as the following :

1. ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {}
   ```
2. ```
   public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
   ```

Comment: One is asynchronous and the other is not. You can use the await keyword with number 1 but not with number 2.

Comment: Why do developers use these methods ? What purpose does it serve by using method 1 and 2. Sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: With method one, you can do asynchronous programming, so, for instance, in your Controller, you want to do a file download from the database but also you need to do some other data pulls or pushes, you can use method 1 to run a task to do that process and continue with code in the main thread, spawn another task to do another file download or upload, (Parallel Programming), then await those 2 tasks to finish before returning from the method. This can be a lot faster than method 2 depending on how many actions you need to take and how many actions depend on a result from a previous action.

Comment: Try reading this, it answers your question and talks about sync vs async:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158789/why-should-i-create-async-webapi-operations-instead-of-sync-ones

Comment: @RyanWilson What about method (2)

Comment: @sharonHwk async/sync aside you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49504573/5233410

Comment: Is it possible to return a `bool` (a return type) with method (2) ?

Comment: @sharonHwk can you clarify that last comment about the bool? As an action can basically return any object type. It is how the framework deals with them that may differ

Comment: @RyanWilson All endpoints in an ASP application are going to run on a thread pool thread.  There is no "main thread" in an ASP application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1 is an asynchronous API Action, returning a simple ActionResult, which is a base type for action method return types.

Method 2 is a synchronous API action, returning a generic IActionResult type that encapsulates a collection of strings.

Considering the method names `Get`, they are the kind of APIs that you would call to get some data from a web server.

Does this answer the question?